# How to make an isosceles triangle with spaces inside

Tags: java

I need to make an isosceles triangle with spaces inside like this

`Enter the size of the equal sides in an isosceles triangle: 6
*
**
* *
*  *
*   *
******`

What I had so far is a triangle without spaces.

```
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the equal sides in an isosceles triangle: ");
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i,j;

    int a = num.nextInt();
    for(i=0; i < a ; i++) 
    {    
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++) 
        { 
            System.out.print("*"); 

        } 

        System.out.println(); 
    }
```

Anyone can help me finish this out?

Comment: Try to consider what you actually want to print for different values of `(i, j)`. It seems to me that there's two specific values `j == 0` and `j == i` where you want to print an asterisk, and most of the time you'd rather print a space.

Comment: I tried to make a condition inside the second loop but it seemed complicated with the space I have to print out for the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation which I like.  It uses a ternary expression to compute, for each value of `i` and `j`, what the character to be printed is.  We choose to print a `*` when one of the following is true:

- It is the first or last character on a given line
- It is the last row of the triangle

Otherwise, we print a space.  Have a look at the code sample below.

```
int a = 6;
for (int i=0; i < a ; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        char chr = (i == a-1 || j == 0 || j == i) ? '*' : ' ';
        System.out.print(chr); 
    } 

    System.out.println(); 
}

*
**
* *
*  *
*   *
******
```

### Demo